# MySQL - sort result by specific record

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Perhaps someone could tell me, how to order MySQL output in this specific scenario:

I have table like this:

```
| id  | Value1 | Value2 | ...More values that doesn`t matter in this example
^-----^--------^--------^
|  1  |   1    |    X   |
|  2  |   2    |    X   |
|  3  |   3    |    2   |
|  4  |   1    |    X   |
|  5  |   2    |    X   |
|  6  |   3    |    3   |
|  7  |   1    |    X   |
|  8  |   2    |    X   |
|  9  |   3    |    1   |
```

I want to get values from this table, and I want to order them by Value2, but only there, where Value1 is 3 (X values doesn't matter).

What`s the best way to do this, with good performance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what do you want to happen when `value1` is not equal to 3?

Comment: I wasn't precise enough: Let's say, that I want to get just the id key, but from whole table, and order those keys, that do have Value1=3 by Value2. So my desired output would be like: (9, 3, 6, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8), and I do care only about order of (9, 3, 6) - I need the rest, but in any order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, do you want `where` and `order by`?

```
select t.*
from t
where value1 = 3
order by value2;
```

EDIT:

Based on the comment:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (value1 = 3) desc, -- put value 3 first
         value2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Value1=3 ORDER BY Value2
```

Comment: Simple and good, but I need to select all rows, not only those, that do have Value1=3

Answer (score 0):

Try with this please:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Value1=3 ORDER BY Value2 UNION SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Value1!=3
```